# PHP Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

after installing payment gateway in WooCommerce, first there was the following error *"Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by tap-gateway.php:69"*.

After searching in this file, I edited it and remove from this:

```
        $this->ui_mode = $this->get_option('ui_mode');
        $this->save_card = $this->get_option('save_card');
        ?>

        <?php
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'payment_scripts' ), 11);
        add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
```

the following:

```
        ?>

        <?php
```

I hope what i did was right.

Any way now I am having another issue with the same file that I couldn't fix:
*"A non-numeric value encountered in public_html/wp-content/plugins/tap-payments/tap-gateway.php on line 262"*

Here is the related code:

```
 // line 261
 $sub_total += ($item['quantity'] * $product['price']);

 // line 262
 echo '<input type="hidden" name="items_bulk[]" data-name="'.$item['data']->name.'" data-quantity="'.$item['quantity'].'"
```

can some one help?

Comment: The code from that payment gateway seems badly written and obsolete since WooCommerce 3.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec you are 100% right

Comment: There are many duplicates with your exact error message, please try searching before posting a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you meant line 261, as

```
$sub_total += ($item['quantity'] * $product['price']);
```

could certainly cause that warning if `$item['quantity']` or `$product['price']` contained anything other than a numeric value.

Rewriting line 261 to

```
$sub_total += (intval($item['quantity']) * floatval($product['price']));
```

would ensure they are [cast](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) to integers prior to multiplying them.

**UPDATE**

Change line

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="items_bulk[]" data-name="'.$item['data']->name.'" data-quantity="'.$item['quantity'].'" data-sale-price="'.$item['data']->sale_price.'" data-item-product-id="'.$item['product_id'].'" data-product-total-amount="'.$item['quantity']*$item['data']->sale_price.'" class="items_bulk">';
```

to

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="items_bulk[]" data-name="' . $item['data']->name . '" data-quantity="' . $item['quantity'] . '" data-sale-price="' . $item['data']->sale_price . '" data-item-product-id="' . $item['product_id'] . '" data-product-total-amount="' . intval($item['quantity']) * floatval($item['data']->sale_price) . '" class="items_bulk">';
```

for the same reason as above.

I do however echo LoicTheAztec's comment on your question that this payment gateway seems badly written.

Comment: nope that didnt work still gives me errorPHP Warning:  A non-numeric value encountered in public_html/wp-content/plugins/tap-payments/tap-gateway.php on line 262

Comment: nope that didnt work still gives me errorPHP Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in public_html/wp-content/plugins/tap-payments/tap-gateway.php on line 262

Comment: Note that the product price is a float number, not an integer… Also in that case, it's recommended to use `intval()` and/or `floatval()`than `(int)` and/or `(float)`.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec quite right, thank you for pointing that out :-) I've updated my answer for clarity

Comment: @LoicTheAztec am not that good in PHP just starting up, if you dont mind could you please solve it for me

Comment: @Sam sorry Sam .. still it gives me the same error

Comment: @AhmadTaher could you link to where you got the plugin from, as https://wordpress.org/plugins/tap-payments/ doesn't seem to have `tap-gateway.php` (and hasn't been updated for a year..)

Comment: @Sam they provide V2.0 from their side .. you can download it from here https://filebin.net/lhsxjtpnzo6tgoag/tap-payments__40_.zip?t=byfj3542

Comment: @AhmadTaher I've updated my answer above

Comment: @Sam that work like a charm ... thanks man ..u made my day :)

Comment: Note that since WooCommerce 3, `floatval($item['data']->sale_price)` should be replaced by  `floatval($item['data']->get_sale_price())` as product (object) properties are protected and doesn't have to be accessed directly.